# spring cronsequencegenerator pattern for job that run on 9th, 16th, 23th and 30th of every month at 10 O'clock.

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am struggling with the spring cronsequencegenerator pattern for job that run on 9th, 16th, 23th and 30th of every month at 10 O'clock.

Please help.

Comment: Please describe what you tried, the exact error messages, your environment, etc..

Answer (score 0):

**Spring provides a solution**

Go through the documentation of [Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation and you be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's 10AM and not 22:00 basic cron exp for you would be

`0 10 9,16,23,30 * *`

As per documentation cron-like exp is needed

`0 0 10 9,16,23,30 * *` - with additional first field for seconds.

Depending on specification (implementation) of "cron-like" your needs could suit

`0 0 10 9,16,23,30 * ?` - with day of the week special symbol

`0 0 10 9,16,23,30 * * *` - with optional field for year filled in